# How to keep song playing when component is rendered or changed and also update play/pause status in bottom navbar using react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

ReactJs.

1. A Home page where list of album names are shown say 'album abc'.
2. User clicks on the album 'abc' and sees a list of songs associated with that album say song1, song2, song3.
3. User plays song1 (song is played)

Now here is what I am trying to do,
After the 3rd step I want the bottom music navbar to show the song name when it is played and show the playing icon. (just like jiosaavan and other apps do)

Also when I play the song and move to another component the song gets paused.
[ I am playing song using ref ]

Note: My code is not good and so i am looking from start to end
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using component in app.js just like navHeader, and keep music details inside that component which will not then rendered every time you change the component, may this help.

```
<Router>
      your list of route here...

     <musicPlayer/>
</Router>
```

Comment: hey @livecoder, thank you for answering , yes I am trying but i want to change the status as well when song is played on any page it should show the name and playing status in the bottom nav liike spotify and other apps do.